# Email send not working after symfony_mailer upgrade

Tags: 10

I'm trying to upgrade symfony_mailer from 1.x to 4.x. The upgrade went smoothly and the test email button works, but the code we use to send emails is giving this error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported operand types: null + array in Drupal\symfony_mailer\Plugin\EmailBuilder\LegacyEmailBuilder->build() (line 107 of modules/contrib/symfony_mailer/src/Plugin/EmailBuilder/LegacyEmailBuilder.php)
```

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
  $to = new Address($to, $toname, $language->getId());
  $from = new Address($from, $fromname, $language->getId());
  $htmlMessage = $payload->getMessage();
  $converter = new Html2Text($htmlMessage, ['do_links' => 'table']);
  $textMessage = $converter->getText();
  $result = $this->mailer2->newTypedEmail($module, $key)
    ->setTo($to)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->setReplyTo($reply)
    ->setBody([
      '#markup' => $htmlMessage,
    ])
    ->setTextBody($textMessage)
    ->setSubject($payload->getSubject())
    ->send();
```

It seems I need to define "legacy_message" somewhere, but adding a setParam('legacy_message', $htmlMessage) doesn't work because setParam isn't valid at that "phase".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to change the code to this:

```
  $mail = $this->mailer2->newTypedEmail($module, $key, [
    'id' => $module,
    'send' => TRUE,
    'module' => $module,
    'key' => $key,
    'subject' => $payload->getSubject(),
    'body' => [Markup::create($htmlMessage)],
  ]);
  $to = new Address($to, $toname, $language->getId());
  $from = new Address($from, $fromname, $language->getId());
  $mail->setTo($to);
  $mail->setFrom($from);
  $mail->setReplyTo($reply);
  $mail->setTextBody($textMessage);
  $result = $mail->send();
```